# Slow response of onTouchListener for Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I need fast response for onTouchListener on any view for Android Wear.
(I need the exact Action.Down time and start processing some sensor data).

I tested on the phone and it is immediately.
However on Android Wear (LG G Watch), it has something like 100-200ms before showing the result.
Please see video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RAb6pgKAqw

I used the following minimal code (most of them are auto generated when I start new project in Android Studio)
I just added a onTouchListener, it set a textview with current uptime so that I know it is a new touch down. 
I am aware that a watch is slower than a phone, but 200ms delay for a touch is too much.

Anyone know why or how to improve the response speed?
It is important for my app to have fast response.

Another way around is to always minus 200ms for every onTouch I detected?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
            stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                    mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);
                }
            });

            stub.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            mTextView.setText("Touch DOWN " + SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because you had enabled the triple click to zoom feature under "Accessibility" settings. (Magnification gestures)
Disable it pls.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the problem.
It was because I enabled the triple click to zoom feature under "Accessibility" settings. (Magnification gestures)
After I disable it, it is much faster now.